# Can you state the existence of the orthogonal projection on $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $V$ be the $ℝ$-space of the continuous functions of $[0,1]$ in $ℝ$, with the product $\langle f, g\rangle = ∫_0^1 f (t) g (t)\, dt$. Let $W$ be the
set of constant functions.

Can you state the existence of the orthogonal projection on $W$? If so, describe it, if not, justify it.

**Attempt:** By contradiction suppose that there exists the projection $E$ of $V$ in $W$. Then as $\dim W< \infty$, it follows that $V = W \bigoplus W^ \perp$. But

$W^ \perp = \{ f \in V; \langle f, c\rangle =0 \,\,\ \forall c \in W \}$.

that is

$0=\langle f, c\rangle = ∫_0^1 f (t) c \,dt \,\,\ \forall c \in W $

that is
$0=∫_0^1 f (t) \,dt \,\,\ \forall c \in W $.

But if we take $f (x) = x$, then $f\in V$, $f\notin W$, 
then it must belong to $W^ \perp$. But $1=∫_0^1 t dt=∫_0^1 f(t) dt$. contradicting $V = W \bigoplus W^ \perp$.

Is this right?? I find it strange because the later exercise says so:

Show a formula for $p_{W^⊥}(f)$ where $p_{W^⊥}$ is the orthogonal projection on $W^⊥$.

And to show this, do I need the above projection of this exercise to be correct?

Comment: $W$ is a 1-dimensional space spanned by the constant function $\boldsymbol{1}$. So it should be fairly easy to find an explicit projection onto $W$. A standard trick is to let $P_W$ be defined by $P_W(f)=\langle f,\boldsymbol{1}\rangle\boldsymbol{1}$. Then $P_W$ is clearly a projection onto $W$. Does it annihilate $W^\perp$?

Comment: It's not true that $v\in W\oplus W^\perp $ and $v\notin W$ implies $v\in W^\perp$.

Comment: @BenW  My argument is really wrong. The projection you write really nullifies $W^ \perp$

Comment: Where does $\dim(W) < \infty \implies V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ come from?

Comment: Theorem $5$ section $8.2$ Hoffman, is only to have projection of $V$ in $W$.

Comment: It is easy to mix up between $V=A \bigoplus B$ and $V = A\bigcup  B$. For the latter, any element belong to V should belong either A or B. But for the first, an element belong to V may not necessary belong to either A or B. It is the sum of an element in A and an element in B. So, to your question "is it right?", the answer is no. The contradiction reasoning is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to minimise $\|f-c\|$ over constants $c$. This is equivalent to
minimising $\|f-c\|^2$ over constants $c$ and is much more tractable.

Expanding gives
$\|f-c\|^2 = \|f\|^2 + c^2 - 2 c\langle 1, f \rangle$, and the minimising $c$ is given by
$c= \langle 1, f \rangle$.

Hence the projection is given by $Pf = \langle 1, f \rangle$.

It is straighforward to check that $P$ is orthogonal, 
$\langle c,  f - Pf \rangle = c \langle1, f \rangle  -c \langle1, f \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error, $f(x)=x\in V$ so you have that $f(x)=g(x)+c$ for some function $g\in W^\perp$ and constant function $c$.

The orthogonal space will be

$W^\perp=\{f\in V: \int_0^1 f(x)dx=0\}$

Infact every continuos function $f\in V$ can be written as

$f(x)=(f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)dt)+\int_0^1 f(t)dt$

The orthogonal projection on $W^\perp$ will be simply

$p_{W^\perp}(f)=f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)dt$